# iOS Sharekit Semantic issues

Tags: ios, sharekit

I'm using sharekit for twitter integration. Application works fine with sharekit but compiler shows 25 warnings for semantic issues.  Since app is running fine,is it ok to leave this issues without fixing them? Will leaving those issue crash the application for some users?

Comment: Depends on the warning… you should post an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, that you use latest [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/). There is only one warning left, coming from 3rd party API. If you decide to use try it, the best might be to reimplement it from scratch and follow [install wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit). There were many changes since the original share kit.

Answer (score 1):

As a general programming principle you should have no errors or warnings... Many programmers consider any warning an error... Personally I like to see 0 warnings... They are telling you something...